# Optimizing multiple if-else condition in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a REST API which will provide search results based on specific search criteria.
User can search using Department Id, User Id and Joined Date.
So here, user can search in 7 different combinations.

1. Search only with Dept Id
2. Search only with User Id
3. Search only with Joined Date
4. Search with Dept Id & User Id
5. Search with User Id & Joined Date
6. Search with Dept Id & Joined Date
7. Search will all 3 criteria (Dept Id, User Id & Joined Date)

According to our application's current design, For each criteria I would have to call different services in different order for information.

For instance : We have an existing User service which has user details, a Department service which has details. So if user searches only for User ID, I would directly go to UserService. If user searches with Dept ID & User I would first have to query Dept service and then the User service.

My current code is:

```
if(Util.hasOnlyUserId(searchCriteria)) {
        searchResponse = searchWithUserId(searchRequest);
    } else if(Util.hasOnlyJoinedDate(searchCriteria)) {
        searchResponse = searchWithDate(searchRequest);
    } else if (Util.hasOnlyDeptID(searchCriteria)) {
        searchResponse = searchWithDeptId(searchRequest);
    } else if (Util.hasUserIdAndDeptId(searchCriteria)) {
        searchResponse = searchWithUserIdAndDeptId(searchRequest);
    } else if (Util.hasUserIdAndDate(searchCriteria)){
        searchResponse = searchWithUserIdAndDate(searchRequest);
    } else if (Util.hasDeptIdAndDate(searchCriteria)) {
        searchResponse = searchWithDeptIdAndDate(searchRequest);
    } else if (Util.hasAllCriteria(searchCriteria)) {
        searchResponse = searchWithAllCriteria(searchRequest);
    }
```

Here, searchCriteria is my request object (POJO) which has these search elements as private members.

searchResponse here is a type of SearchResponse object which is the actual response of the API and it contains the user's details like name, id, position, lastSalaryDrawn, CommuteType, MaritalStatus and Last Promoted Date

I have been trying to optimize this multiple if-else condition in other words, avoid having this multiple condition.
I tried to separate each of them and put them into different methods. But this just isn't satisfying me and it seems like it is in an un-optimizable state.

Any ideas on how I can go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit : We are using JPA to interact with the MySQL.
The problem here is I will not get the information in a straight forward manner from a DB. So building a dynamic query might not work.
The information needs to be fetched from multiple micro services, which will in turn make a call to their native DB and send the required information as a response.
I hope this make sense.

Comment: This kind of questions should be asked at [codereview.SE]. because it is about optimizing of running code

Comment: You can take a look on the chain of responsibility design pattern : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: What is the type of `searchResponse`? Assuming response is of `User` type, I would make single service which will handle all the cases via single select build from provided criteria.

Comment: @matoni I have edited the question and added an explanation for search response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions how to improve working code belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jens I didn't know a Code Review forum existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the code to the place where the criteria is executed and build the query dynamically:

```
public SearchResponse searchWithCriteria(Criteria searchCriteria) {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...");
    if (util.hasUserId(searchCriteria))
        query.append(" AND userId = :userId");
    if (util.hasJoinedDate(searchCriteria))
        query.append(" AND joinedDate = :joinedDate");
    ...
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    if (util.hasUserId(searchCriteria))
        stmt.setString("userId", searchCriteria.getUserId());
    if (util.hasJoinedDate(searchCriteria))
        stmt.setDate("joinedDate", searchCriteria.getJoinedDate());
    ...
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. But I have edited the question with the reason why I will not be able to go by this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Code could be optimized with [Strategy pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy).

Comment: Please provide an answer instead of linking to external resources (which may rot away over time)

Answer (score 0):

Various patterns can be used here, and you have to choose one depending on how the code of the search looks like. Some people have already mentioned the Strategy and Chain of Responsibility patterns. Another one you could look at is the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern. It allows you to have optional parts which are only specified if you need them, to build the final object.

So you could have a `SearchBuilder` class that updates the information about the search as you add more filterning criteria. It could have methods like `setUserId(...)`, `setDeptId(...)` etc.

For example: If the search was being translated to a plain SQL query in a `PreparedStatement`, whenever one of the filtering fields is set, the builder would store them (they would start as `null`). So if in your builder you had called setUserId() and setDeptId(), those would not be `null` inside the builder and you generate a query with the string (appending `AND ...` for each extra field you want to filter with):
`select * from users where id=? AND dept_id=?`

The `SearchBuilder` could offer a `build()` method which then returns a `Search` object which carries the query and maybe even offers the method that does the query, or whatever you need to do.